# Error in *.xlsm file when writing strings using xlsm

Tags: openpyxl, xlsm

I am using openpyxl (2.3.2) to write out an xlsm file. I can write the numeric values correctly but the string values are corrupting the xlsm file. In the code example below, the xlsm file is corrupted but the xlsx file works well

[image: work]

When I open the xlsm file , I get a error

> we found a problem with some content in samp2.xlsm

On continuing, I see only the numeric values are written and not the string values. This does not happen with the xlsx file.

This is a strange problem

**PS** The "Samp.xlsm" and "Sample.xlsx" Files are new files saved with these names. They do not have any content. 
Appreciate any suggestions/feedback

Comment: It's impossible to say without the actual files but there was at least one bug related to text processing fixed in subsequent releases.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, these are new files saved with no content in them.

Comment: Then I suspect the problem is that the XLSM file does not contain any VBA parts.

Comment: Spot on. I had to put in a VBA macro and it worked. Thanks !